# SQL Database join tables

Tags: sql-server, database

i want to create a view listing name and surname of all authors who have won a Guardian prize, but i cant get to join the two tables so they return only the authors that wont Guardian prize. Any ideas ? Thanks

```
CREATE DATABASE [Books Database]

CREATE TABLE [Books]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [book name] [NVARCHAR] (75),
    [year published] [int],
    [book prize won] [NVARCHAR] (75),
)



INSERT INTO [Books] ([book name], [year published], [book prize won]) VALUES
('Amsterdam',1998, 'Booker prize'),
('The God of Small Things',1997, 'Booker prize'),
('The Cost of Living',1999, NULL),
('Last Orders',1996, 'Booker prize'),
('The Sweetshop Owner',1997,NULL),
('How Late it Was, How Late',1994 , 'Booker prize'),
('Spirit Level',1996, 'Whitbread Poetry and the Whitbread Book prizes'),
('Behind the Scenes at the Museum',1995  , 'Whitbread Book prize'),
('Emotionally Weird',2000, NULL),
('Human Croquet',1998, NULL),
('Felicia''s Journey' ,1994, 'Whitbread Novel and the Whitbread Book prizes'),
('Every Man for Himself',1996, 'Whitbread Novel prize'),
('Midnight''s Children',1980, 'Booker prize'),
('The Satanic Verses',1988, 'Whitbread Novel prize'),
('The Moor''s Last Sigh',1995 , 'Whitbread Novel prize'),
('Larry''s Party',1998, 'Orange prize'),
('Fugitive Pieces',1997 , 'Orange and the Guardian Fiction prizes'),
('Reading in the Dark' ,1996 , 'Guardian Fiction prize'),
('Debatable Land',1994, 'Guardian Fiction prize')


CREATE TABLE [Authors]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [author name] [NVARCHAR] (75),
    [author surname] [NVARCHAR] (75),
    [nationality] [NVARCHAR] (75),
    [yob] [int],
    [prizes won] [int]
)


INSERT INTO [Authors] ([author name], [author surname],[nationality], [yob], [prizes won]) VALUES
('Ian', 'McEwan', 'English', 1948, 1),
('Arundhati','Roy', 'Indian', 1961, 1),
('Graham','Swift', 'English', 1949, 1),
('James','Kelman', 'Scottish', 1946, 1),
('Seamus','Heaney', 'Irish', 1939, 2),
('Kate','Atkinson', 'English', 1951, 1),
('William','Trevor','Irish', 1928, 2),
('Beryl','Bainbridge','English', 1936, 1),
('Salman','Rushdie','Indian', 1947, 3),
('Carol','Shields','American', 1950, 1),
('Anne','Michaels','Canadian', 1955, 2),
('Seamus','Deane','Irish', 1940, 1),
('Candia','McWilliam','Scottish', 1955,1 )
```

Create a view listing name and surname of all authors who have won a Guardian prize.:

```
CREATE VIEW View1 AS
SELECT [author name], [author surname], [book prize won]
FROM [Books Database].[dbo].[Books]
JOIN .........
WHERE [book prize won] LIKE '%Guardian%'
```

Comment: Why the mysql tag?

Comment: Seems  you haven't relation between books and author  .. how you think to join these to tables if there anren't relations ?

Comment: removed the MySql tag based on the syntax.

Comment: Please read about [mvce]s for when your code doesn't work. Eg here, you would give what .....s have you tried and what was the output/error of each. (But see comment the by scaisEdge using what you've given so far.)

Comment: Based on the information supplied, you can't. There is no table linking books and authors. Are you certain these are all the tables? If this is what your lecturer gave you to solve.... he needs to learn how to do his job properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no link between Books and Authors, so there's now way to join the tables. If I ask you to manually name those authors from your example, what would be those and on what criteria would you evaluate you answer?